# Timeout on OpenLogic repository

Tags: centos, azure, mirror

I'm trying to use the OpenLogic repository on CentOS as describe [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-centos#centos-70):

```
[openlogic]
name=CentOS-$releasever - openlogic packages for $basearch
baseurl=http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/openlogic/$releasever/openlogic/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Several days ago it was working OK, but now I'm getting:

> [Errno 12] Timeout on
> http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/openlogic/7/openlogic/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
> (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')

Is anyone struggling with the same problem? Is the mirror really down or it has been disabled/moved?

*I tried to find any status page for this service, but no success...*

Comment: Looks down to me. Keep in mind that guide is very out of date and there should be no need to alter your repos.

Answer (score 0):

These commands worked for me after uncommenting the mirror list in the /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file and running the following

# yum clean all

sudo yum clean all

# yum update

sudo yum --disablerepo=openlogic update

# yum install

sudo yum --disablerepo=openlogic install git

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve my problem. I need to install packages from the `openlogic` repo, so disabling it is not an option.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello What's in that repo that you could possibly need?! It's just an outdated copy of the official CentOS repos.